# Is there a way to sync or backup photos to Ubuntu laptop (14.04) from Android Galaxy S7 remotely

Tags: sync

Over the last few days I've been looking for alternatives to cloud options such as Dropbox etc. for a way to save, sync, or back up photos from my Galaxy S7 to my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop when I travel internationally in a few months time instead of using a cloud option. (I don't like the idea of having my files stored on a 3rd party server)

Earlier today I found Syncthing, which looked perfect for what I wanted. However, because I will only be taking my phone, and leaving my laptop at home, it turns out Syncthing won't work as both devices need to be on during the transfer or sync.

So, my question, does anyone know of an open source system (similar to Syncthing) to in essence for simplicity purposes, transfer photos from my phone directly to my laptop when the laptop is turned off?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? You certainly won't be transferring anything to your laptop when it's turned off.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of a few motherboards (for example, my Z97) it is impossible to transfer to a device that is turned off

This makes me wonder about my own hardware at times but nonetheless, what you are describing is illogical

If you want to transfer to a device, it must be active/switched  on to receive your data, otherwise a 3rd part must be involved, this is for holding your data

Some solutions to your problem if you do not want a 3rd party involved would be installing a networked file server to your local network and accessing that from your phone, you could also have a cheap phone at home, acting a fileserver, or even your modem may have a USB port for such purposes, allow it to have access from outside WAN addresses, set yourself up with a good password and connect to it from your phone, if your modem is capable you may be able to achieve more with ww-drt